# Receiving incomplete data through promise $q angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, indexeddb, angular-promise

Am having variations with the data i expect to get, when i console log the object that have 3 main elements with the message:

```
HERE ARE THE VARIATIONS IN THE ARRAYS , then the results are:
Object {usr: Object, cat: Array[2], exp: Array[2]} // Incomplete data
Object {usr: Object, cat: Array[3], exp: Array[3]} // complete data
```

Am getting this data from indexedDB using DexieJS library. I got a function that call 3 functions to get all data which is usr, cat, exp. Am missing the data in cat and exp functions. My guess is missing for using bad promise.
This is what get the data for cat(and exp is almost the same with change names):

```
regresarCat: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var cats = [];
        var count = 0;
        db.transaction("rw", db.categories, function () {
            db.categories.orderBy('nameCat').each(function (cat) {
                cats[count] = cat;
                count++;
                deferred.resolve(cats);
            });

        }).catch (function (e) {
            deferred.reject(e);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

The get all data function(regresarTodo) is the next:

```
regresarTodo: function(){
var deferred = $q.defer();
var todo = [];

this.regresarUsr().then(function(user){
    todo['usr'] = user;
    deferred.resolve(todo);
    return deferred.promise;
}).catch(function(e) {
    deferred.reject(e)
});

this.regresarCat().then(function(cate){
    todo['cat'] = cate;
    deferred.resolve(todo);
    return deferred.promise;
}).catch(function(e) {
    deferred.reject(e)
});

this.regresarExp().then(function(exps){
    todo['exp'] = exps;
    deferred.resolve(todo);
    return deferred.promise;
}).catch(function(e) {
    deferred.reject(e)
});

$q.all({ usr: this.regresarUsr(), cat: this.regresarCat(), exp: this.regresarExp() }).then(function(respuesta){
    console.log('Got promise');
    console.log(respuesta);
    deferred.resolve(respuesta);
});

return deferred.promise;
}
```

I can't find my error, i see those variations because i am calling the regresarTodo function with an interval and i see that the first time not always is complete and sometimes second print is complete but keeps the variation. I need to get all the data at the first time. Am very lost, thanks

Comment: @WayneEllery That would not work. The `.each` callback is called asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `deferred.resolve(cats)` inside an `.each()` handler, but a promise should never be `resolve()`d more than once.

The library you are using provides a `.toArray()` method, so you should use that.

You also don't need to create a promise from scratch using a deferred object; `.toArray()` and `db.transaction()` create promises for you:

```
regresarCat: function () {
    return db.transaction("rw", db.categories, function () {
        return db.categories.orderBy('nameCat').toArray();
    });
}
```

Notice how this also makes your function about 70% shorter.

---

You have a similar problem in your second code sample. You are trying to resolve a single `deferred` in three different places, when you don't need to use deferreds here at all. You can just pass your promises directly into `$q.all()`:

```
regresarTodo: function() {
    return $q.all([this.regresarUsr(), this.regresarCat(), this.regresarExp()])
    .then(function(respuesta){
        console.log('Got values');
        console.log(respuesta);
        return { usr: respuesta[0], cat: respuesta[1], exp: respuesta[2] };
    });
}
```

Note again how this makes your code about 80% shorter. Also note that the argument to `$q.all()` should be an *array*.

Comment: great i liked a lot your solution :D, i change the regresarCat function for your code and now i can see in the console a t object which i can see in dev chrome how i can click and see the _value with Array[3], am trying to get the value and did this:
var categorias = function(){
      var uno = MGAindexdb.regresarCat();
      console.log('Dentro de categorias');
      console.log(uno); // which print t {_state: null, _value: null, _deferreds: Array[0], _catched: false, _PSD: null…}
    }
I try to log the value but I get null and when click I see the objects

Answer (score 0):

You basically need a different deferred object for each call. And you need to resolve the corresponding deferred after data from that call is received.

Then subsequently form an array with all the above deferred objects' promises and use that array in

```
$q.all(allPromisesArray).then(function(){
    /* your stuff here */
})
```

Comment: There isn't actually a need to use deferred objects at all here.